# Characterising adverbial constructions

Tags: syntax, adverbs, conjunctions

I know adverbs are multifarious, but I’d like to find out just how farious they are. I’m trying to work out what properties they can have by looking at variations in the way different ones can be used. I’m especially interested in how they relate to conjunctions.

I find (1) below perfectly natural, whereas (2) hurts my ears:

(1) *Although he was sick, he nevertheless went in to work*

(2) *Because he was sick, he therefore stayed at home*

I’m not sure at this point whether the problem [that I perceive] with (2) is syntactic or semantic, but I’d like to understand the syntax better.

*Although* and *because* are both subordinating conjunctions, so it seems reasonable to expect them to behave in the same way. On that basis any syntactic issue must be to do with *nevertheless* and *therefore*.

*Nevertheless* is an adverb that modifies a clause by flagging that whatever it expresses might be unexpected given whatever has just been said.

*Therefore* is an adverb that modifies a clause by flagging that whatever it expresses is a consequence of whatever has just been said.

If I take out *although* and *because*, the two adverbs seem to behave in more or less the same way:

*He was sick but nevertheless went into work*

*He was sick and therefore stayed at home*

*He was sick; nevertheless, he went in to work*

*He was sick; therefore, he stayed at home*

The only difference I can really find is that *therefore* demands a comma if it is moved to the end, whereas *nevertheless* is happy without one.

*Therefore* has been described as a connective, but I think that must also be true of *nevertheless*, which has to refer back to whatever it is that sets up the expectation.

Is it possible that they are both connectives but that they connect different syntactic units? It feels as though, in (2), the referent of *therefore* includes *because*, whereas, in (1), the referent of *nevertheless* does not include *although*. I do not know how I could describe that in linguistic terms, though.

I also have a vague feeling that there is a determiner or quantifier hiding in *therefore* but not in *although*. I can't really articulate it any better than that so don't know how to test this idea. Perhaps it's just another way of saying that the scope of the referent is different.

Comment: "Although" and "because" are best analysed as prepositions, not subordinators, see here:[link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/although) and here: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/because). Try re-analysing your examples with that in mind.

Comment: @BillJ thanks, but as long as they are in the same category (and provided it's not a catch-all category like 'adverbs') I think the analysis would come out the same. I'm interested in why it might be better to categorise them as prepositions and checked out the links, but the reasoning doesn't seem to be given.

Comment: @BillJ doesn't (2) suggest that *because* conveys not only that one clause expresses a cause, but also that the other clause expresses its consequence? If not *because I was tired I therefore went to bed* would be OK. If *because* marks two separate clauses in this way, I can't see how it can be a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll have a go at answering the question myself, in the hope that others will chime in:

While *therefore* and *nevertheless* are both connective adverbs, they differ syntactically in that *therefore* cannot connect to an element which is lower in the tree.

The problem with *because he was sick, he therefore stayed at home* is that the only possible referent of *therefore* is lower in the tree, in the subordinate clause.

*Nevertheless* is not so picky.

*However* is similar in meaning to *nevertheless* but behaves more like *therefore* in this respect:

x *although he was sick, however he went in to work* / x *because he was sick, therefore he stayed at home*

*he was sick; however he went in to work* / *he was sick; therefore he stayed at home*

*he was sick but, however, went in to work / he was sick and, therefore, went in to work*

Although *however* is redundant in the last example, the sentence strikes me as grammatical.

It seems therefore that connective adverbs are characterised, in part, by whether they can take a subordinate clause as their referent.

Comment: I think the problem with 'although...however' and 'because...therefore' is that each has complete semantic redundancy.  cf 'because...thereafter' which works since 'thereafter' constrains time but not causation.